# i want to call javascript pop up on Linkbutton but it post back the page and pop up is disappeared

Tags: javascript, asp.net

## Javascript code:

```
function showdlgBox()
{
    var whiteBox = document.getElementById("white-background");
    var dlgbox = document.getElementById("dlgBox");
    whiteBox.style.display = "block";
    dlgbox.style.display = "block";`enter code here`
    var winwidth = window.innerWidth;
    var winHighet = window.innerHeight;`enter code here`
    dlgbox.style.left = (winwidth / 2) - 480 / 2 + "px";
    dlgbox.style.top = "150px";
}
```

## html:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

How to Call this javascript on `linkbutton`?

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

As far as I understand it, that

```
OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
```

gets linked to the back end (server side) function - this is why the post back occurs.

**Solution:**

Perhaps try taking it out. Or alternatively, use pure html anchor tag:

```
<a id='LinkButton1' href='javascript:void(0)'></a>
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Call javascript function `onclientclick`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" onClientClick="return showdlgBox()">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

and in javascript function return false;

```
 function showdlgBox() {
            var whiteBox = document.getElementById("white-background");
            var dlgbox = document.getElementById("dlgBox");
            whiteBox.style.display = "block";
            dlgbox.style.display = "block";`enter code here`
            var winwidth = window.innerWidth;
            var winHighet = window.innerHeight;`enter code here`
            dlgbox.style.left = (winwidth / 2) - 480 / 2 + "px";
            dlgbox.style.top = "150px";
            return false;
        }
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

use `OnClientClick="showdlgBox();"`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  OnClientClick="showdlgBox();">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use modal in bootstrap..

[link of modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)